# Different ActiveRecord association update behavior when running individual specs vs. full suite in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a spec that looks something like this:

```
foo.members << bar
# test some aspect of bar which assumes its membership in foo
```

- When I run the spec individually (either at the command line with rspec pointed at the file, or with guard running either the whole file or just the single example after detecting file changes), it passes.
- When I run the entire test suite (either the entire thing, or actually just invoking the entire thing but with `:focus` on the single example so that it's still the only one that runs, just like in the first bullet point above) it fails.

This fixes it:

```
foo.members << bar
bar.reload # <-- the fix
# test some aspect of bar which assumes its membership in foo
```

So for some reason, in the first case, bar's membership is properly updated in memory, and in the second case it is not. Why?

Comment: Have you confirmed you're test DB has the exact same architecture as you're dev env?

Comment: it's the same server instance on my local machine -- what do you mean by architecture?

Comment: I mean your test DB schema.

Comment: yep, i'm sure that the test db is made with the same schema

Answer (score 1):

You may want to isolate which other spec in your suite (there may be multiple) is interfering with the test in question. I would suggest you kick off the specs for just that file and one other file at a time, continuing to do so until you find a test file that makes this spec fail (this can either be done manually or via a shell script). Let us know once you have isolated the other spec that is interfering with this one, and then we can go from there.

As a general rule, and as you're probably aware, tests should be independent of each other and should never interfere with each other. Make sure that no spec is stubbing out a method or leaving stuff created in the database, for example.